# Will JSON work if JavaScript is disabled in the browser?

Tags: json, blogger

I was looking at the code in my Blogger template for the threaded comments because I wanted to find out how the `<div>` is a direct descendant of the `<ol>`? I don't think that is supposed to be so(Correct me if I'm wrong and cheer me on if I am right. I'm new to this).

Here is the thing,

I see the threaded comments are using `<script type="text/javascript">`, so I disabled JavaScript in my browser(Chrome), went back to a Blogger blog with a page with threaded comments and they were threaded.

The JSON stuff is in the same `<script>` to make the threaded look, which got me confused.

Does that mean that JSON is read and works even though JavaScript is disabled or is it something else?

Comment: Which blogger page/template are you refering to? We need URIs!

Comment: If you disable client scripts, no client script will be able to play around with JSON data. Without scripts, the "threaded look" must have been created elsewhere.

Comment: @Bergi Here is an example: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2012/01/google-account-authentication-using.html#comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when viewing source you will see that the comments get delivered *both* as inline json data and usual html. So the script (when active) doesn't need to retrieve the data from the dom to build its model structure.